# How to get list of all objects from two models related with one to one field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a client profile model as follows

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and a auth user model. I want list of all user objects with their address to a json like:

```
{
    //auth_user fields
    "username": "username",
    "first_name": "first_name",
    "last_name": "last_name", 
    "is_active": true, 
    "is_superuser": false, 
    ....
    ....
    //UserProfile fields
    address: "address"
}
```

By doing `serializers.serialize(User.objects.all())` I could only get auth user data. How to get associated profile data also with user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to serialize each model seperately. Apart from that, if you really need to return json of a single record for both models, you could build a list of dictionaries from the models manually (eg by iterating) and then use `json.dumps` instead of the Django serializer:

```
import json
# ...

r = []
for user in User.objects.all():
    r.append({
        'username': user.username,
        # ....
        'address': user.userprofile.address
    })

 my_json = json.dumps(r)
```

Haven't tested this but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

To get nested object serialization you could use part of django-rest-framework - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    userprofile = UserProfileSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User

serializer = UserSerializer(user)
print(serializer.data)
```